# Kotlin coroutines MDCContext isn't restored

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mdc

Just playing around with coroutines and logging MDC.
I have a dummy example

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/dummy/{delay}")
suspend fun dummyEndpoint(@PathVariable delay: Int): ResponseEntity<String> {
    logger.debug("Outside the context. Start")
    withContext(MDCContext(mapOf("myKey" to "myVal"))) {
        logger.debug("Inside the context. Before the call")
        val response = WebClient.create()
            .get()
            .uri("http://postman-echo.com/delay/${delay}")
            .retrieve()
            .awaitBody<String>()
        logger.debug("Inside the context. After the call")
    }
    logger.debug("Outside the context. End")
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK")
}
```

It produces next log message:

```
2020-07-30 19:42:09,817 - [DEBUG] - [reactor-http-nio-3] - [{}] Outside the context. Start
2020-07-30 19:42:09,836 - [DEBUG] - [reactor-http-nio-3] - [{myKey=myVal}] Inside the context. Before the call
2020-07-30 19:42:15,411 - [DEBUG] - [reactor-http-nio-4] - [{myKey=myVal}] Inside the context. After the call
2020-07-30 19:42:15,412 - [DEBUG] - [reactor-http-nio-4] - [{myKey=myVal}] Outside the context. End
```

My expectation was that the context will be cleared after `withContext()` block will be finished.

Inspired by https://medium.com/@elizarov/phantom-of-the-coroutine-afc63b03a131

*This is more verbose, but it also avoids the need to restore the context after the call to doSomeWork.*

So why the last message outside the context is still contains MDC values? or I'm missing something?

Comment: You can do a `yield()` after the `withContext` block, to force `restoreThreadContext` of `MDCContext` to run.

Comment: Just tried it. It didn't help

Comment: Turns out [there is a discussion on github](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/985#issuecomment-535075092) on exactly the same issue.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is the same problem discussed. If I add one more `withContext(MDCContext())` on top-level it will be successfully restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the one of the comments the issue is discussed in https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/985

It seems that it was fixed in one of the latest releases.